# rpm + where RPM installed the files/scripts PATH

Tags: linux, bash, rpm

I installed the following RPM file

```
rpm -Uvh --repackage /var/tmp/bash-3.2-33.el5_11.4.i386.rpm 
warning: /var/tmp/bash-3.2-33.el5_11.4.i386.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key      ID 37017186
 Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
 Repackaging...              
 1:bash                   ########################################### [100%]
 Upgrading...                
 1:bash                   ########################################### [100%]
```

Please advice where I need to find the bash script ? (where rpm located the script ) ?

Comment: This is far more likely to install (mainly) a bash executable, than a script. Are you looking for a particular script that might be in that package  or for a specific (old) version of the bash executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to try:

```
rpm -ql bash
```

Comment: when I run it I get along list , it is possible to verify only the relevant bash script that installed from the RPM?

Comment: To find executable files: `rpm -ql bash | xargs -I {} find {} -type f -executable`